# Como mapear atributos multivalorados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, atributos

Estou tentando fazer o mapeamento desse modelo conceitual para o lógico, mas tenho dúvida sobre como mapear o atributo multivalorado "palavra_chave" que permitirá o cadastro de quantas palavras chaves o usuário desejar. Tenho que criar outra tabela? Como fica as chaves primárias e estrangeiras?

[image: modelo_conceitual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu faria uma nova tabela para essas palavras chaves. Ficaria:

[image: Tabela]

perceba que o P é de Primary Key, F de Foreign Key, o asterisco vermelho é nulidade (obrigatório).

Answer (score 1):

Para seu modelo de dados estar em primeira forma normal (1FN) é preciso que os atributos sejam atômicos, ou seja, não podem ser multivalorados.
Note que existem SGBDs que permitem o uso de atributos multivalorados mas, neste caso, analise com bastante cuidado para não ter problemas futuros.
Siga a dica da Melanie.